# Smart GIT issue short read of block

Tags: hard-drive, git

I'm learning about GIT and I am using SMART GIT.

I am running Windows 10 but using a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu.

I have cloned and committed using SMART GIT - all works fine. The issue is when I close the session (saving state or restart computer). When I next load the VM and open SMART GIT, under the repositories tab instead of showing the branch name, it shows `<unknown branch/commit>`. If I attempt to sync or create a new branch or add a new repository to the same location on my hard drive I get the error message

> Executing a command has failed
>   Short read of block

It's not clear to me where the error is - with the Virtual Machine, Ubuntu or Smart GIT...

Is there anything I can do to find out what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by a very similar looking issue (with no solution) [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/2e53y2/smartgit_issues/) (noted it's old), my money would be on SmartGit. Looking at [this link](https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Installation+and+Files) you should likely be able to determine it definitively by looking at SmartGit's log file:

> **Default Location of SmartGit's Settings Directory**
>     **Windows**
>   %APPDATA%\syntevo\SmartGit\ (%APPDATA% is the
>   path defined in the environment variable APPDATA)
>   **Mac OS**
>   ~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/<major-smartgit-version>
>    **Linux/Unix**
>   ~/.smartgit/

...

> log.txt contains debug log information. It can be configured via log4j.properties. You may remove this file: afterwards, SmartGit will return to its default logging settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, weirdly enough in almost exactly the same setup: Win 10 host, Debian VM, SmartGit in the VM, VM was terminated hard.

In my case, it was simply caused by a corrupt git repository. When I did a `git log` on the command line, I got error messages about empty object files. Also, `git fsck --full` was segmentation faulting, which just cannot be a good sign.

I started to delete the empty object files, `find . -size 0` was helpful here. Ultimately, I could fetch, pull and checkout in SmartGit again.

Some topics that guided me on my journey (even though none of them covered exactly my case or repair steps):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678853/how-to-fix-corrupted-git-repository
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271263/repair-corrupted-git-repository/8706206
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725925/git-repository-corrupt-incorrect-header-check-loose-object-is-corrupt/47183245